# Batch finish method getting null values

Tags: apex, batch, stateful

I'm implementing an apex batch process.

```
public class BatchName implements Database.Batchable<XYZClass.wrapper>,Database.Stateful{
```

I have declared an integer variable as public and assigning value to it in execute method.

```
Public Integer Counter=0;
```

When I try to access it in finish method, I am getting null value.

While declaration, when i set it to zero, I'm getting zero.
I'm unable to get the assigned integer value.

I'm using the database.stateful, as it allows you to maintain state.

Please help me. Am I overlooking anything here?

Comment: Anurag, can you share more of your code than just the first line?

Comment: Best to add the definition of your variable to the question (as e.g. static wouldn't work).

Comment: You need to give us more context if we are to help you.

Comment: I edited the question above, i was using static variable while declaration. Keith's suggestions help me that static doesnt work.. Thanks Keith..!!

Comment: No Adrain. The comments solved my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm):

> **Using State in Batch Apex**
>
> Each execution of a batch Apex job is considered a discrete transaction. For example, a batch Apex job that contains 1,000 records and is executed without the optional scope parameter is considered five transactions of 200 records each.
>
> If you specify Database.Stateful in the class definition, you can maintain state across these transactions. **When using Database.Stateful, only instance member variables retain their values between transactions. Static member variables don’t retain their values and are reset between transactions.**

The following works for me...

```
public class Throwaway implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful
{
    public Integer batches;
    public Throwaway() { batches = 0; }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope)
    {
        batches++;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        system.assert(false, batches);
    }
}
```